# CSS positioning absolute vs. relative

Tags: html, css

I have an `<a>` tag in my HTML that I need a drop-down to always be displayed below when the user clicks on the link. Without the click event, it looks something like this:

HTML

```
<a class="parent">Learn more</a>
<div class="child">This is the stuff for learning more</div>
```

CSS

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
}
```

However, the child div is not lining up with the `<a>` tag if there is content before the a tag.

How can I ensure the dropdown is always appearing below the `<a>` tag even if there's content before it?

Comment: You can use <ul></ul> instead of using <div></div>

Answer (score 4):

Not with the code you have there.

You have missed something when it comes to relative/absolute positioning. For the absolutely positioned element to align with the relatively positioned element, the relative element needs to be a parent. That's not a parent, it's a sibling, and won't work.

To fix this, you'll have to rethink it somehow. You could use javascript to always align the element with the link, or you can wrap the whole bit in something like another div, akin to this:

```
<div class="parent">
  <a>Learn more</a>
  <div class="child">This is the stuff for learning more</div>
</div>
```

and CSS something like this:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 1.5em; // to clear the <a>
}
```